# how to detect a url path with jquery and change css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tumblr

So I'm working on a Tumblr theme and i want the index (or home) page of the tumblr to display a div that I don't want the user to see on the following index pages.

For example, I want **"myblog.tumblr.com"** to have a big splash div with a tall height (let's call give this an id "homesplash"), while any pages under **"myblog.tumblr.com/page/"** to hide this div so the user can see the posts first. So like **"myblog.tumblr.com/page/2"**, **"myblog.tumblr.com/page/3"**, and so on.

How do I do this with jquery? How do I detect any url that contains **"myblog.tumblr.com/page/"** and hide that div? Appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with jQuery per se, but you can just use `window.location.pathname`.

```
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('page') > 0) {
   $("#splash").hide();
}
```

Comment: I tested this on a test page in my dropbox and it seems to work great! Just what I needed, good looking out.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has the answer. Then hook the results into some logic with jQuery. More [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-jquery).

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```